# mapping Date in AZure Data Factory

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

Im working with Data actory this time this why i ask lot of question about that

My new problem is that my SOURCE(CSV file contains a column DeleveryDate  full of Date dd/MM/YYYY) and my table SQl where i specify DElevry date as DateTime but when I map btw source and sink in Data preview source
[image]

duplicate columns like in the picture below but in data preview sink the columns always NULL the same in my table NULL.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: You said column DeleveryDate full of Date dd/MM/YYYY), can you tell me why the column DeleveryDate has the values like '3', '1' ? I don't think '3' or '1' are the date string with format  `dd/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: I don't know why he put this numbers instead of Date however the mapping is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said column DeleveryDate full of Date dd/MM/YYYY), can you tell me why the column DeleveryDate has the values like '3', '1' in your screenshot? String '3' or '1' are not the date string with format `dd/MM/YYYY`.

If you want to do some data convert in Data Factory, I still suggest your to learn more about [Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview).

For now, we can not convert date format from `dd/MM/YYYY` to datetime `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` directly, we must do some other converts.

Look at bellow, I have a csv file contained a column with date format `dd/MM/YYYY` string, I still using [DerivedColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) this time:

[image]

**Add DerivedColumn**:

[image]

Firstly, using this bellow expression to substring and convert `dd/MM/YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-dd`:

```
substring(Column_2, 7, 4)+'-'+substring(Column_2, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(Column_2, 1,2)
```

[image]

Then using `toTimestamp()` to convert it:

```
toTimestamp(substring(Column_2, 7, 4)+'-'+substring(Column_2, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(Column_2, 1,2), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image]

**Sink settings and preview**：

My Sink table column tt data type is datetime:

[image]

**Execute the pipeline:**

[image]

**Check the data in sink table:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-
This is a trick which was a blocker for me, but try this-

1. Go to sink
2. Mapping
3. Click on output format
4. Select the data format or time format you prefer to store the data into the sink.
   [image]